# If condition with Time & Date

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, time, conditional-statements

`if (31/05/2023 23:45 < 01/06/2023 00:00)` gives False as a result in excel

if condition comparing < to determine which date is bigger, excel is giving wrong answer. help me correct the issue.
suggest me with correct if condition

Comment: May be they are in text format. not sure what you have on your end, you have not shown any screenshots as well

Comment: `if (--"31/05/2023 23:45" < --"01/06/2023 00:00","TRUE","FALSE")`

Comment: @ScottCraner - or drop the IF? Returning text-that-looks-like-a-boolean is a pet peeve , sorry :-)

Comment: i just put in one cell 31/05/2023 23:45 and in another 01/06/2023 00:00 and in next cell trying to find if cell 1 < cell 2 answer is false

Comment: There you have your answer given by @ScottCraner Sir

Comment: @BigBen agreed, but since the OP did not show the results for true and false I just put them there as place holders.

Comment: i do not know how to share screenshot

Comment: What is the date format you are using? If you are from US then it will be mm/dd/yyyy and hence dd/mm/yyyy will not work, will be taken as text. can you add those double unary as shown by @ScottCraner Sir and try

Comment: can some one put exactly  this in a cell a tell me again the issue cell a1 enter 31/05/2023 23:45   cell a2 01/06/2023 00:00 then in cell a3 enter a1<a2    let me know the answer

Comment: select the date and hit `CTRL+SHIFT+~` and see whether they are returning as number or not?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift +~ cell not returning numbers.

Comment: Certainly yes, if you do that, it will confirm you whether those are numbers or not as in Excel, dates and times are stored as numbers that said for `31/05/2023 23:45` it will return `45077.9895833333` while for the latter `45078` which determines which is greater and which is not. if doesnt returns as numbers then its text, you need to use proper date format as per your regional settings.